# How do I get a value from a `HashMap::<&'static str, u32>` using a String as the key?

Tags: rust

With a `HashMap::<&'static str, u32>`, how do I get a value from an owned `String`?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3cb3edaad0f27ff69f38a6389dbe918b)

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::<&'static str, u32>::new();
    
    let s = "foo".to_string();
    
    map.insert("foo", 12);
    map.insert("bar", 42);
    
    println!("foo={}", map.get(&s).unwrap());
    println!("bar={}", map.get("bar").unwrap());
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&str: Borrow<String>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:28
   |
11 |     println!("foo={}", map.get(&s).unwrap());
   |                            ^^^ the trait `Borrow<String>` is not implemented for `&str`
```

Using a `&'static str` directly [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=896def7da81bb5ffdc74ca55b811f369):

```
println!("foo={}", map.get("foo").unwrap());
```

Strangely, inserting a `&str` from the owned `String` also [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5433399f6193d8ebdc55af0cff75c867):

```
let s = "foo".to_string();
map.insert(&s, 12);
```

I think that's only because Rust can tell the map doesn't outlive the string, change it to a static map and the borrow checker rightly complains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&s[..]` to convert the `String` into a `&str`:

```
println!("foo={}", map.get(&s[..]).unwrap());
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=34a2b5307c2cb2395c19244ac6e1d793)

Comment: `s.as_str()` also works if the `&[..]` syntax feels too magical.

Comment: This works, but I don't understand why. So normally &String get's coerced into &str through the Deref trait defined on String. Why didn't that work here? Why does the &s[..] syntax work?

Comment: `Borrow<String>` vs `&str`?

Comment: @AsceticBear yes, normally &String gets implicitly converted to &str because of the deref trait, right? So why did that fail here?I don't understand why &s was fine for insert and not for get. The reason has to do with Borrow<String> right?